# ADF: Column name or path duplicated in 'source' under 'mappings'

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, columnmappings

I am getting following error during pipeline run.

```
Operation on target ac_ApplyMapping failed: Column name or path 'StudentId' 
duplicated in 'source' under 'mappings'. Please check it in 'mappings'.
```

In the Copy Activity we are applying following mappings.

```
{
    "type": "TabularTranslator",
    "mappings": [{
            "source": {
                "name": "StudentId",
                "type": "string"
            },
            "sink": {
                "name": "StudentId_Primary",
                "type": "string"
            }
        }, {
            "source": {
                "name": "StudentId",
                "type": "string"
            },
            "sink": {
                "name": "StudentId_Secondary",
                "type": "string"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there any way to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Derived column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-derived-column) transformation to change the column name in the source, and then mapping to your sink.